# Regex match for comma delimited string

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string which is legal.

```
1-5,10-15
```

Using the following regex, I get a false for match.

```
^[^-\s]*-?[^-\s]*$
```

It works fine for things like

- 1-5,10
- 1,5

which are all legal. But it won't handle comma delimited ranges. What am I missing?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match?

Comment: Why not use String.Split()? It would be better for comma delimited strings than regexing the parts out.

Comment: Seconding above comment: Why assume that a regex is what you need?

Comment: Regex makes the matching process easier for all the different combos that can come about.

Comment: Why not both? Split the strings on commas, and apply the regex to each resulting string. You can still test for illegal strings that way, but don't have to monkey with parsing out comma-related problems.

Comment: What is the benefit to that extra step and processing? If I can get one regex to handle everything, there isn't much point in writing extra code.

Comment: @Gregory Dodd, I think you are over thinking this. I have added an answer that uses only String.Split() and doesn't require the overhead of using the regex engine. Since your list is first delimited by commas and then by dashes, you don't need regexes. Just perform two splits and parse out the parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this pattern,

```
^\d+(\-\d+)?(\,(\d+(\-\d+)?))*$
```

it will match on the following strings:

```
1-5,10-15,5
1,2,3-5,3-4
1-5,10-15
10-15
10-15,5
```

but not on

```
1-,10-15,5
1,2,3-5,3-
1-510-15
10-15,
,10-15,5
```

- [Screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16021179/Screenshot%20for%20StackOverflow/regex.JPG)

Comment: [Regexper Result](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16021179/Screenshot%20for%20StackOverflow/regex2.JPG)

Answer (score 6):

where's the handling for a comma? try to visualize your regex in [regexper](http://www.regexper.com/)

now try this:

`^(\d+-?\d+)(?:\,(\d+-?\d+))+$`

[image: screenshot from regexper.com]

Update: my regex is not a solution as you might have very specific needs for the captures. However, that nifty tool might help you with the task once you see what your regex does.

Comment: Wow, that is a great site. Thanks.

Comment: here's your result if you test your regex. [Click Here.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16021179/Screenshot%20for%20StackOverflow/regex3.JPG)

Comment: @JW 웃: yup. I meant to show how one could go about visualizing it without spelling out the answer

Comment: its a great tool to see our regex visually

Answer (score 1):

The best regex I know for splitting comma separated strings is:

```
",(?=(?:[^\""]*\""[^\""]*\"")*(?![^\""]*\""))"
```

It will not split an entry in quotations that contains commas.

E.g. Hello, There, "You, People" gives

Hello

There

You, People

Answer (score 1):

```
^(\s*\d+\s*-?\s*\d*)(\,(\s*\d+\s*-?\s*\d*))*$
```

It takes care of starting spaces, followed by at least 1 digit. "-" is optional and can be followed by one or more digits. "," is optional and can be followed by the same group as before.

Matches:

1,5

1-5,5-10

15,2,10,4-10

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using just splits:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace RangeTester
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "1,2,3,1-5,10-15,100-200";
            string[] ranges = str.Split(',');
            foreach (string range in ranges)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(GetRange(range.Trim()));
            }
            Console.Read();
        }

        static string GetRange(string range)
        {
            string[] rng = range.Split('-');
            if (rng.Length == 2)
                return rng[0] + " to " + rng[1];
            else
                return rng[0];
        }
    }
}
```

I was over thinking the solution to this problem, but since you know that your list of numbers/ranges will be first delimited by commas and then by dashes, you can use splits to parse out the individual parts. There is no need to use regular expressions for parsing this string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
^\d+(-\d+)?(,\d+(-\d+)?)*$
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want something like `(\d+)-(\d+)` to get every range. Example [here](http://rubular.com/r/QTncT757Sz).

Answer (score 0):

I think this should also work fine.

```
^\d*(-\d*)?,\d*(-?\d*)?$
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: it failed on some set of string. [Click here.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16021179/Screenshot%20for%20StackOverflow/regex4.JPG)