# Use RegEx to get error handling for inputting pages

Tags: regex, vb.net, error-handling

> Hello this code was by Chris, Combined to MackieChan solution

looking to the codes I'm very lost, I couldn't figure it out how to ADD a range.

I meant like this:

I'm trying to change or update the code from detecting commas for pages,

The code below shows how to input pages with commas,

sample: 1,2,5,3,8 and it would not accept 0, or greater than the maximum page

What I'm asking is to add the code that would accept like this:

2-5,8,9
or
8,9,2-5
so it means, pages to print are 2,3,4,5,8,9

or
2,4-6,9,8
so it means, pages to print are 2,4,5,6,8,9

```
private rgxNumberWithComma As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^([0-9]+,?)+$")
Public Function CheckInput(ByVal valyo As String, _
             ByVal origMaxPage As Integer) As Boolean

Dim match = rgxNumberWithComma.Match(valyo)
If Not match.Success Then
    Return False
Else
    Dim numbers as new List(Of Integer) ‘will store added numbers
    For Each Item In valyo.Split(","c)
        Dim intValue As Integer
        ‘Check if number is a valid integer
        ‘Check if number is 0
        ‘Check if number has already added the number list
        ‘Check if number is greater that MaxPage
        If Not Integer.TryParse(Item, intValue) _
                   OrElse intValue > origMaxPage _
                   OrElse intValue = 0 _
                   OrElse numbers.Contains(IntValue) Then
            Return False
        Else
            ‘Item is valid, continue
            Numbers.Add(intValue)    
        End If
    Next
End If
Return True
End Function
```

Comment: This is at least the second comma-delimited regex question today! Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/17614911/1100441

Answer (score 1):

You could use this to verify the string:

```
^[0-9]+(-[0-9]+)?(,[0-9]+(-[0-9]+)?)+$
```

This will also ensure that the string doesn't start or end with a comma.

For evaluating the string, I'd suggest this:

```
Dim numbers as new List(Of Integer) ‘will store added numbers
For Each Item In valyo.Split(","c)
    Dim parts = Item.Split("-"c)
    If parts.Length > 1 Then
        ‘Evaluate range
        Dim minValue As Integer
        Dim maxValue As Integer
        If Not Integer.TryParse(Item, minValue) _
                   OrElse Not Integer.TryParse(Item, maxValue) _
                   OrElse minValue > maxValue _
                   OrElse maxValue > origMaxPage _
                   OrElse minValue = 0 Then
            Return False
        Else
            For value As Integer = minValue To maxValue 
                If numbers.Contains(value) Then
                    Return False
                End If

                ‘Item is valid, continue
                numbers.Add(value)
            Next
        End If
    Else
        Dim intValue As Integer
        If Not Integer.TryParse(Item, intValue) _
                   OrElse intValue > origMaxPage _
                   OrElse intValue = 0 _
                   OrElse numbers.Contains(IntValue) Then
            Return False
        Else
            ‘Item is valid, continue
            numbers.Add(intValue)    
        End If
    End If
Next
```