# split array and get last value of each index

Tags: c#

I have a string which looks like this

```
string sortOrder= "download-15104,download-15103,download-15105,download-15106,download-15107,download-16104,download-16105";
```

And i want just ids . So , i did this

```
var ids= new List<int>();
var sortOrderArray = sortOrder.Split(',');
foreach (var item in sortOrderArray)
{
    var obj = item.Split('-');
    ids.Add(int.Parse(obj[1]));
}
```

Is there any other way to do this and do this quick ?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: try using regex. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614911/regex-match-for-comma-delimited-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use LINQ:

```
var ids = input.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x.Split('0')[1])).ToList();
```

But, **it will not be faster**. It uses loops internally anyway. It may just be much more readable.

Comment: can't we avoid loop anyway ?

Comment: Even `string.Split` uses loop to iterate over all characters in a string. Why would you like to avoid loop?

Comment: as per you answer i see 3 loops in this code . So isn't this bad ? i am just asking not pointing you

Comment: I don't think you should be concerned about that.

Comment: @Jade are you sure you put a comment under correct answer? :)

Comment: i know your code is almost same in speed as mine , but i marked it correct because if its not speedy atleast it short . Linq made our lifes . Thanks

Comment: I did a quick profile, this executes alot quicker than the RegEx solution, and only a bit slower than mine :(

Answer (score 1):

```
var ids=Regex.Matches(sortOrder,@"\d+(?=,|$)")
             .Cast<Match>()
             .Select(m=>int.Parse(m.Value));
```